# How do I know what NaturalEarthFeature names are available for cartopy?

Tags: cartopy

The [cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/feature_interface.html#cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature) class of cartopy looks like a very convenient way to add high quality map features, but I haven't been able to figure out what values are allowed for the `name` parameter at class initialization. The documentation indicates it needs to be a valid dataset name from [www.naturalearthdata.com](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/), but the dataset information there does not give clear indication of the datasets' names.

I have tried the obvious such as 'natural-earth-i-with-shaded-relief' (or variant 'natural_earth_i_with_shaded_relief') and other such guesses, but none of my guesses worked. The only names that don't drop a 404 on me are 'land' and 'ocean' under the 'physical' category -- but even then, although the code runs it doesn't render anything for those features. I am expecting some sort of basic land or ocean shading at the very least. Ideally I would like to add physical shaded relief as a backdrop to my data overlay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: What are the values allowed for the `name` parameter of the cartopy command below?

```
cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature(category, name, scale, **kwargs)
```

Answer: The `name` can be figured out from the (shapefile) file names in the depository:

```
https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector
```

For example, at scale '50m' of cultural category, the link is [here](https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/tree/master/50m_cultural):

In that place you will find many shapefiles. One of it is

```
ne_50m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land.shp
```

The `name` parameter of this file is only part of it (without 'ne_50m_'):

```
"admin_0_boundary_lines_land".
```

With this example, I hope you can figure out any file you want.