# Names of NaturalEarth features

Tags: cartopy

I would like to plot the boundaries of the UK countries using `cartopy`.  According to the NaturalEarth website https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-details/ these are `map units` of level `admin_0` cultural data. I am trying to load them with the following Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.UTM(zone=30, southern_hemisphere=False))
borders = cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature(
    category='cultural',
    name='admin_0_details_map_units_lines',
    scale='10m',
    facecolor='none')

ax.add_feature(borders, edgecolor='gray')
```

but get the error `HTTPError: Not Found`.  I am guessing that I have the `name` argument wrong. I have tried various combinations such as

```
name=admin_0_details_map_units
name=admin_0_map_units
name=admin_0_mapunits
name=admin_0_mapunits_lines
```

but get the same error.  Can anyone suggest a name string that might work?  As a more general question, is there a list of such strings for other data?  There does not seem to be anything on the NaturalEarth website that indicates how such strings should be formed.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just found the answer here:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62402312/how-do-i-know-what-naturalearthfeature-names-are-available-for-cartopy?rq=2>

Comment: Dont forget to give feedback. It could be outdated.